# disable next button until all methods loaded

Tags: vb.net

net and I've a few methods in my pageload. And my page is having prev and next buttons. Here I want to disable next button until all methods loaded successfully.

In my case what is happening is user clicking next button before all methods loaded successfully and he is getting error. Because next page should load based on current page methods only.

I'm not using ajax. Is there any other way to disable next button until all methods loaded?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the page with the button disabled and then activate it once all the methods are loaded.